# 301 redirect front page only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I created 2 pages when starting my blog: the first page which only serves as a 'summary' of what my blog is about and the second page which is the one with actual content.

I don't want to keep the first page anymore because it seems pointless, so I want to 301 redirect it to the second page. But the first page is set as the front page and has the url of `example.com`. The second page is on `example.com/second-page/`.

I know that the redirect in the htaccess file should be done like this:

`Redirect 301 /old-page.html /new-page.html`

But my front page has no URL slug, so how do I write it?

Would `Redirect 301 / /second-page/` work or would that redirect every page on my domain?

Note that I only want to redirect the front page and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, this will redirect home page(based on your shown samples) eg--> `http://localhost:80` TO `http://localhost:80/second-page/`. Please clear your browser cache before you test your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/?$ second-page [R=301,L]
```

Comment: By the way, do forward slashes in the URL slug matter here? I mean does writing `second-page` or `second-page/` or even `/second-page/` make a difference?

Comment: @R2vale, yeah it matters, depending upon for which thing you are using, if you have specific question, requirement then I would like to request you to open a new question with all the details and we can discuss it there more, cheers.